# IAR define memory region for custom data

Tags: c, linker, embedded, stm32, iar

I want to define a specific memory region in the STM32 micro where to store some strings. I'm using IAR compiler but I don't find a simple example that can help me to create the region in the correct way using the icf file. How can I create the region and use this region in the code? Thanks

Comment: Is that example (http://supp.iar.com/Support/?note=27498) unclear?

Comment: Yes is not clear because in the example you can see the allocation of functions. In my case I want create a memory region of example 1K where to put a list of string.

Comment: Such an expensive toolchain and no support?

Comment: I always hope for a quick answer here! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solution:

In the icf file I define the memory region in this way:

```
define region LANGUAGE_region   = mem:[from 0x080FB000 to 0x080FC000];
"LANGUAGE_PLACE":place at start of LANGUAGE_region  { section .LANGUAGE_PLACE.noinit };
```

I will fill this region with an external srec file using a programmer.
To test the region with a simple program (using an integer) I use this declaration:

> In the header:
>
> ```
> extern const unsigned int mydata @".LANGUAGE_PLACE.noinit";
> ```
>
> In the C file:
>
> ```
> const unsigned int mydata;
> ```

In the debugger I can see the correct address of mydata constant at 0x0800FB000

Comment: You want to store strings inside an integer....? How does this code make any sense, given the question? Shouldn't you rather have a 2D array of characters?

Comment: The important for me was to find a way to create the region in the flash. I used an integer in the example code only to test if the start address of my region was respected. Then I will try to put the string array,